# react router canot work properly for me

Tags: reactjs

i have a problem ..i am setting routers in my application but when i clicked on second link both components appear at the same time

```
return (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <div>
      <div className="sidenav">
        <img 
          src={require("../src/images/logo-light.png")} 
          style={{maxWidth:'20vh',maxHeight:'60vh',marginLeft:'2vh'}}
        />
        <a><NavLink to="/">Home</NavLink></a>
        <a><NavLink to="/function2">Function2</NavLink></a>
      </div>

      <div className="content" style={{minHeight:'94vh',maxHeight:'0vh'}}>
        <Route 
          path="/" 
          render={() => 
            <Home come={this.coming} sendname={{newname:this.state.username}}/>
          } 
        />
        <Route path="/function2" render={() =><Fun2 />} />
      </div>
    </div> 
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

tell me where is the problem
i also added screen shot of my application
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FCcz.png)

Comment: Is this React Router v4?

Comment: yes..............

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to wrap your `<Route>`s inside `<Switch></Switch>` and might want to add `exact` attribute to your index route

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <div>
    <div className="sidenav">
      <img src={require( "../src/images/logo-light.png")} style={{maxWidth: '20vh',maxHeight: '60vh',marginLeft: '2vh'}}/>
      <a>
        <NavLink to="/">Home</NavLink>
      </a>
      <a>
        <NavLink to="/function2">Function2</NavLink>
      </a>
    </div>


    <div className="content" style={{minHeight: '94vh',maxHeight: '0vh'}}>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" render={()=> <Home come={this.coming} sendname={{newname:this.state.username}}/>} />
        <Route path="/function2" render={()=> <Fun2 />} />
      <Switch>
    </div>
  </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: I thought you wanted to see only either one of them? Does clicking the `/function2` link not work? By the way, I edited this post slightly because it wasn't correct before.

Answer (score 0):

In React Router you need to add a switch which will only select one of the path.

Also for the root path you should add **exact** into your props so that it matches only on that path.

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/" render={()=> <Home come={this.coming} sendname={{newname:this.state.username}}/>} />
  <Route path="/function2" render={()=> <Fun2 />} />
<Switch>
```

Also remember **ordering** matters. So it will select the first route that matches (which is why adding the props **exact** matters)